# JAXB - IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have an XSD like this:

```
<xs:element name="Measure">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" ref="Measure_Id"/>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs ="4">
        <xs:element ref="Measure_Value"/>
        <xs:element ref="Measure_Value_Max"/>
        <xs:element ref="Measure_Value_Min"/>
        <xs:element ref="Measure_Value_Average"/> 
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="Files"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In particular, with `<xs:choice>` i'd like to specify that element `Measure` must have at least one type of `Measure_Value`.
Unfortunately this kind of code generate an exception:

> com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
>   There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}Measure_Value_Max.

What i have to do to fix this problem?

I use `Netbeans 7.4` and `jdk1.7`.

In addition, in another part of my schema, this type of restriction works correctly! Why?

```
<xs:element name="UD_Info">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" ref="UD_Identificator"/> 
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs ="3">
        <xs:element ref="UD_Measures"/>
        <xs:element ref="UD_Alarms"/>
        <xs:element ref="UD_Diagnostics"/>
    </xs:choice>        
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Stack trace:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/francesco/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/francesco/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.6/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}Measure_Value_Max.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at protected java.util.List com.fra.jaxb.Measure.measureValueOrMeasureValueMaxOrMeasureValueMin
    at com.fra.jaxb.Measure
    at protected java.util.List com.fra.jaxb.UDMeasures.measure
    at com.fra.jaxb.UDMeasures
    at protected java.util.List com.fra.jaxb.UDInfo.udMeasuresOrUDAlarmsOrUDDiagnostics
    at com.fra.jaxb.UDInfo

at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:66)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:405)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:432)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
at com.fra.mavenparser.unMarsh.doInfr(unMarsh.java:56)
at com.fra.mavenparser.Parser.main(Parser.java:26)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the `ObjectFactory` processes you need to either pass it in as one of the classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`, or create the `JAXBContext` on the package name of the generated model.

Comment: If i well understand your answer, i already generate classes and all perfectly works without the specification that element Measure must have at least one type of Measure_Value. When i insert that type of specify (that you could see in code), i reply this exception.

Comment: @Zany - How are you creating your `JAXBContext`?  Also can you edit your question to include more of the stack trace?

Comment: I used xcj for binding schema to classes (i'll insert info of stack trace info in the question)